# How to smooth edges of drawn image?

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgimage

I'm using this code to colorize some images of a UIButton subclass:

```
UIImage *img = [self imageForState:controlState];

// begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, NO, 0.0f);
// get a reference to that context we created
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// set the fill color
[self.buttonColor setFill];

CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);

// translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// set the blend mode to multiply, and the original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeScreen);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

// set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw the colored image
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

// generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//return the colored image
[self setImage:coloredImg forState:controlState];
```

But the images come out with rough edges.  I've tried using screen, lighten, and plusLighter blend modes, because some of the images have white parts that I want to stay white.  The only part I want colorized is the black areas.  I've attached the original button images, and after they've been colorized.  I can't get the edges to look good.  When I had them as white images that were colorized using multiply blend mode, it looked much better.  But I want to use black so I can use one method for colorizing images with and without white in them.  I tried with anti-aliasing, that didn't help either.  It looks like it just isn't anti-aliasing it.  I haven't worked with Core Graphics enough to know what's up with it.

**EDIT**
Here's what the original PNGs look like:
[image: original image]

and here's what it should look like:
[image: should look like]

and here's what it does look like:
[image: does look like]

The size if different, but you can see the bad quality around the edges.

Comment: Could you post a mockup of what you want it to look like and what it does look like instead?

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the fact that the outside of the image has grey pixels from the anti-aliasing.  Don't know how to fix that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your original icons (PNGs?) are just "too sharp"? Could you show us? You just draw the image at its original size without resizing, so the problem could be right from the start.

Comment: I added some images to my question

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what is what you are trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to round the edges of the images? If so, you are better of by changing the round corner property of the UIButton's layer. Since UIButton is a subclass of UIView, you can get its layer property and change the edge color and round its corner.